# Learning Ethereum development? & idea possibility?

Tags: ether

what are some good places to learn more about ehtereum development/solidity? Usually when learning something new I tend to head to books or treehouse tutorials :) however there is fairly small amounts of resource in this new area?

Also I'm wanting to take development texts online and push out these texts to blockchain/ethereum for intelligent people to answer and push reply back to smart contract. Is this possible? My main query I'm looking to answer is "would I have to market this service like a traditional web business with marketing campaigns", or is there some way/method/framework/third party service where I can push my smart contract transactions for people to see & contribute to. It would be great if I can do this without needing to do traditional marketing. Just being able to push my items to an already populated place where people working on ethereum could see and contribute to my smart contracts when they're looking for contribution.

Answer (score 5):

Starting off (Beginner level) I would suggest checking out Vlad Wulf's youtube channel, hes got some nice quick tutorials introducing you to the basics of solidity via the solidity browser IDE and compiler

Vlad Wulf - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsVoOobxAQL6NbWY2t6E6Sg/videos

For some more intermediate to advanced tutorials check out Jordan Leigh's youtube channel, he goes more in dept creating a React UI to interact with your smart contract

Jordan Leigh - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8CB0ZkvogP7tnCTDR-zV7g

This video in particular of Jordan Leigh's - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-XPBtAfcqo&t gives a great overview of solidity and how to build up a UI to interact with it.

Answer (score 2):

I started with the help of following links and tutorials, that may help you as well. My aim was to learn Ethereum and blockchain basics and then start DApp development quickly.

- Blockchain Whitepaper:  http://scet.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/BlockchainPaper.pdf
- MIT resources on Blockchain: http://blockchain.mit.edu/
- Blockchain essential course by IBM: https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/blockchain-essentials/
- Ethereum Whitepaper: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper
- Geth:  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum (one of the Ethereum Client)
- Solidity Documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ (Go through with it before writing smart contracts)
- DLT Labs YouTube video on Ethereum Basics -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yZ7037M_Lc
- Udemy Course of Ethereum DApp development(10$ only) - https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-developer/
- Videos from Jordan Leigh - https://youtu.be/8jI1TuEaTro, https://youtu.be/3-XPBtAfcqo

Hope this helps.