# Starting with Ethereum for BlockChain

Tags: go-ethereum

I am new to ethereum. I have some knowledge about the fundamentals. What would be the best starting point for gaining more knowledge?

Comment: I [answered](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/21505/7790) a similar question, you may take a look at the reference shared.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Please check the FAQ https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers

Answer (score 2):

If You want to be a *programmer* then start with **solidity Contract** Programming .   You can find alot of stuffs for beginner in **GitHub** and **Ethereum** sites [www.ethereum.org](http://www.ethereum.org) .
If you are Researcher then starts with simple working mechanism of **blockchain and ethereum.**
For solidity programming you can start with **remix** **IDE [remix.ethereum.org](http://remix.ethereum.org) .**
you can easily go through the remix and you can *deploy* the *contract* in **JavaScript VM** or **Injected web3** for **private testnet.**